# Range of values for which the integrals converge

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have two integrals

(i) $\int_\gamma e^{z^2}dz$ where $\{\gamma: z=se^{i\alpha}: -\infty<s<\infty\}$

(ii) $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^\beta dx}{1+x}$

I know that the first integral converges for $\pi/4\le\alpha\le 3\pi/4$ or $5\pi/4\le\alpha\le 7\pi/4$ and the second one converges for $-1<Re\beta<0$ where $Re$ refers to the real part of $\beta$

How can I derive these intervals? I do not see this from simply looking at the integral.